# Background image border radius - white corners

Tags: html, css

I was trying to create Tilt effect on Hover with CSS and JS. I have used Vanilla Tilt JS Library and that works well.

After I wanted to add bottom shadow to images that needs to be tilted on hover, but I have problem with white corners. Images are rounded with `border-radius` and when I hover bottom corner white color is between image and shadow.

Problem:
[image]

My Code

```css
.card-container {
    width: 260px;
    height: 380px;
    background-position: 50% center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }

  .card-container:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 70px -30px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7), 0 50px 100px 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px);
    transform: translateZ(-50px);
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <!-- One Card Code -->
      <div class="card-container" style="background-image:url(https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Unreal+Engine%2FTeaser-Image-3-944x720-54a0ac93e369fd0ee577012df4f1dcd5da67c281.jpg);"
                                  data-tilt=""
                                  data-tilt-glare="true"
                                  data-tilt-max-glare="0.5"
                                  data-tilt-speed="400"
                                  data-tilt-scale="1.08"
                                  data-tilt-max="40"
                                  data-tilt-perspective="500"
                                  style="will-change: transform; transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
                                "></div>
      <!-- One Card Code END -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="card-container" style="background-image:url(https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Unreal+Engine%2FTeaser-Image-2-944x720-e9951a49084478d378346e46bdb026c0b989a479.jpg);"
                                  data-tilt=""
                                  data-tilt-glare="true"
                                  data-tilt-max-glare="0.5"
                                  data-tilt-speed="400"
                                  data-tilt-scale="1.08"
                                  data-tilt-max="40"
                                  data-tilt-perspective="500"
                                  style="will-change: transform; transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
                                "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="card-container" style="background-image:url(https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Unreal+Engine%2FTeaser-Image-944x720-d7a738407387149cc4e941dd18e9486a0c89bb51.jpg);"
                                  data-tilt=""
                                  data-tilt-glare="true"
                                  data-tilt-max-glare="0.5"
                                  data-tilt-speed="400"
                                  data-tilt-scale="1.08"
                                  data-tilt-max="40"
                                  data-tilt-perspective="500"
                                  style="will-change: transform; transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
                                "></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-tilt/1.4.1/vanilla-tilt.min.js"></script>
```

Can someone give me a hint how to fix this?

I have tried to set `overflow` to `none`, but it removes shadow. Also I have tried to "resize" shadow, but it also doesn't helps.

Comment: Shadow disappears if I set `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the shadow on `.card-container` and you can apply `overflow:hidden`:

```css
.card-container {
    width: 260px;
    height: 380px;
    background-position: 50% center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  .card-container:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 20px 70px -30px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7), 0 50px 100px 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
    transition: .3s;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <!-- One Card Code -->
      <div class="card-container" style="background-image:url(https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Unreal+Engine%2FTeaser-Image-3-944x720-54a0ac93e369fd0ee577012df4f1dcd5da67c281.jpg);"
                                  data-tilt=""
                                  data-tilt-glare="true"
                                  data-tilt-max-glare="0.5"
                                  data-tilt-speed="400"
                                  data-tilt-scale="1.08"
                                  data-tilt-max="40"
                                  data-tilt-perspective="500"
                                  style="will-change: transform; transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
                                "></div>
      <!-- One Card Code END -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="card-container" style="background-image:url(https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Unreal+Engine%2FTeaser-Image-2-944x720-e9951a49084478d378346e46bdb026c0b989a479.jpg);"
                                  data-tilt=""
                                  data-tilt-glare="true"
                                  data-tilt-max-glare="0.5"
                                  data-tilt-speed="400"
                                  data-tilt-scale="1.08"
                                  data-tilt-max="40"
                                  data-tilt-perspective="500"
                                  style="will-change: transform; transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
                                "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="card-container" style="background-image:url(https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Unreal+Engine%2FTeaser-Image-944x720-d7a738407387149cc4e941dd18e9486a0c89bb51.jpg);"
                                  data-tilt=""
                                  data-tilt-glare="true"
                                  data-tilt-max-glare="0.5"
                                  data-tilt-speed="400"
                                  data-tilt-scale="1.08"
                                  data-tilt-max="40"
                                  data-tilt-perspective="500"
                                  style="will-change: transform; transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
                                "></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-tilt/1.4.1/vanilla-tilt.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.card-container {
    width: 260px;
    height: 380px;
    background-position: 50% center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .card-container:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 20px 70px -30px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7), 0 50px 100px 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px);
    transform: translateZ(-50px);
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
  }
  .card-container:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <!-- One Card Code -->
      <div class="card-container" style="background-image:url(https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Unreal+Engine%2FTeaser-Image-3-944x720-54a0ac93e369fd0ee577012df4f1dcd5da67c281.jpg);"
                                  data-tilt=""
                                  data-tilt-glare="true"
                                  data-tilt-max-glare="0.5"
                                  data-tilt-speed="400"
                                  data-tilt-scale="1.08"
                                  data-tilt-max="40"
                                  data-tilt-perspective="500"
                                  style="will-change: transform; transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
                                "></div>
      <!-- One Card Code END -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="card-container" style="background-image:url(https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Unreal+Engine%2FTeaser-Image-2-944x720-e9951a49084478d378346e46bdb026c0b989a479.jpg);"
                                  data-tilt=""
                                  data-tilt-glare="true"
                                  data-tilt-max-glare="0.5"
                                  data-tilt-speed="400"
                                  data-tilt-scale="1.08"
                                  data-tilt-max="40"
                                  data-tilt-perspective="500"
                                  style="will-change: transform; transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
                                "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="card-container" style="background-image:url(https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Unreal+Engine%2FTeaser-Image-944x720-d7a738407387149cc4e941dd18e9486a0c89bb51.jpg);"
                                  data-tilt=""
                                  data-tilt-glare="true"
                                  data-tilt-max-glare="0.5"
                                  data-tilt-speed="400"
                                  data-tilt-scale="1.08"
                                  data-tilt-max="40"
                                  data-tilt-perspective="500"
                                  style="will-change: transform; transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
                                "></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-tilt/1.4.1/vanilla-tilt.min.js"></script>
```